# Probability Question With Normal and Exponential distributions

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-function, normal-distribution

The question is as follows, and afterwards - my two possible solutions from which I couldn't determine the correct one:

A company that sells some electrical device runs a call service. $40 \%$ of the customers that call the company are interested in purchasing a new device and their call duration follows the normal distribution with mean $5$ and standard deviation $7$. The other $60 \%$ of calls are questions about the customers' existing device and that call duration follows the exponential distribution with expected value $8$.

What is the probability that a call of a random customer went longer than 6 minutes?

So, first we define a random variable that describes the duration of the calls of those who are interested in a new device as $X_{new} \sim N(5,49)$ and as for the duration of the other aforementioned $60 \%$ we will define $X_{old} \sim exp(\frac{1}{8})$. Now, I'm positive one of the following two calculations is the solution, but which one? I'm stuck for hours...

$1 - [0.4 \cdot P(X_{new} \leq 6) + 0.6 \cdot P(X_{old} \leq 6)]$  OR  $[1 - 0.4 \cdot P(X_{new} \leq 6)] + [1-0.6 \cdot P(X_{old} \leq 6)]$

The final numbers don't matter, it's not a problem to work them out.

Thanks.

Comment: For this exercise you'll want to utilize the total law of probability. Let $T$ be the duration of the customer's call, $N$ be the event that the customer inquires about a new device, and $O$ the event that the customer inquires about an old device. Notice $$T|N\sim \mathcal{N}(5,49)$$ $$T|O \sim \text{Exp}\Big(1/8\Big)$$ So we get that $$P(T>6)=P(T>6|N)P(N)+P(T>6|O)P(O)$$ Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thank you I get it. What you wrote actually translates to my second proposed solution. For whom it may be of interest the answer is $0.4611$.

Comment: Where did this problem come from? It is nonsense to speak of the duration of a call being distributed as $\operatorname N(5,7^2).$ That implies there's about an $8\%$ chance the duration is negative.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\require{cancel} \xcancel{\begin{align}
& 1 - [0.4 \cdot P(X_\text{new} \leq 6) + 0.6 \cdot P(X_\text{old} \leq 6)] \\[8pt]
& [1 - 0.4 \cdot P(X_\text{new} \leq 6)] + [1-0.6 \cdot P(X_\text{old} \leq 6)] \end{align}}
$$
Here's what you need:
$$
0.4\big[ 1 - P(X_\text{new} \le 6) \big] + 0.6\big[1-P(X_\text{old}\le 6)\big].
$$

I.e.
\begin{align}
\Pr(\text{time}>6) & = \Pr\Big( (\text{old}\ \&\ \text{time}>6) \text{ or } (\text{new}\ \&\ \text{time} > 6) \Big) \\[8pt]
&  = \Pr\Big( \text{old}\ \&\ \text{time}>6\Big) + \Pr\Big(\text{new}\ \&\ \text{time} > 6 \Big) \\[8pt]
& = \Pr\big( \text{old}\big)\cdot\Pr\big(\text{time}>6\mid \text{old} \big) + \Pr\big(\text{new})\cdot \Pr(\text{time} > 6\mid\text{new} \big).
\end{align}